# Else does not work

Tags: c#

I am not sure what I am doing wrong! The `else` command and the bracket above it seem not to act correctly:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username_txtb.Text == username && password_txtb.Text == password);
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
    }
    else ;
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have used the wrong username and password. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the semi-colon

Comment: Beginner's rule of thumb: *keywords* always work, and it's always the developer's fault.

Answer (score 2):

```
else ;
```

should be

```
else
```

Remove the semicolon, it will prevent the body from executing.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username_txtb.Text == username && password_txtb.Text == password) //; - remove
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
    }
    else //; - remove
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have used the wrong username and password. Please try again.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

```
else ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
else
{
}
```

So:

```
else ;
{
     //some code
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
else
{
}
{
    //some code
}
```

And more clearly, it's equivalent to:

```
else
{
}

// the conditional clauses are over,
// nothing special here except for an extra scope
// which is a valid construct (even though being useless here)
{
    //some code
}
```

The second block is not really related to the condition - it just a code block in brackets creating a useless scope, and will be always executed.

The same rules apply after `if`.

Comment: When I do this and I enter my correct username and password it tells me correct, but it also says goes to the else and tells me, "You have entered an incorrect username or password!"

Comment: @user3002617 You do what exactly? I didn't gave explicit answer to the question and left it for you to figure it out. It shouldn't be very hard, as in other answers you have the solution given away for free. The behavior you've described suggests, that you didn't follow all of the hints.

Answer (score 2):

The presented code results in a *syntax error* that should read:

> Invalid expression term 'else'

The *syntax error* is caused by the semicolon trailing the `if` (the semicolon after the `else` will result in "unexpected behavior" when running the program, and the same principle applies).

```
if (..);
{
    ..
}
else ..
```

Is equivalent to

```
if (..)
    /* empty statement - no code run when if is true! */ ;

/* arbitrary code in a block *not associated* with the `if` */
{
    ..
}

else ..
```

In this case the "arbitrary code block" *ends* the `if-statement` grammar construct.

To fix the syntax error (and the semantic problem), remove the semi-colons after *both* the `if` and `else` statements:

```
if (..) /* no semicolon */
{
    MessageBox.Show("..");
}
else /* no semicolon */
{
    MessageBox.Show("..");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, took away the semicolon and the top part fixed! Thank you.

Comment: @user3002617 Cool. Remember, it won't be "fixed" until *both* extra semicolons are removed. The semicolon after the `else` will make it appear as if the else "always runs" - it doesn't, as the block is not associated with the `else` statement - even though it will not result in a syntax error as in the former case.